# How can I do the input loop that exits the program?

Tags: java, loops

**"Enter a word or press 'Q' to quit" but I don't know how to do it. It seems confusing to me a little bit.**

**This is my first time coding in Java and I'm still learning.**

```
public class RemSpecialChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            String stringArray = "";
            
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: ");
                String str = scan.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                    if (str.charAt(i) > 64 && str.charAt(i) <= 122) { //returns true if both conditions returns true    
                        //adding characters into empty string
                        stringArray = stringArray + str.charAt(i);
                    }
                    System.out.print("Input string without special characters: " + stringArray); //string results
                }
            }
            while (stringArray != "q" || stringArray != "Q");
        }
    }
}


THIS IS THE SAMPLE OUTPUT:
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: Black?204123,.Scoop (input)
Input string without special characters: BlackScoop (output)
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: q (input)
(end program)


terminal output:
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: q
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: q
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: q
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: q
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: q
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: q
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit: q
Enter a word or 'Q' to quit:
```

Comment: if ("Q".equals(str)) { break; } put this in the beginning of your loop. it should break out of the for loop if you input Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (true) {
                String inputdata = scan.nextLine();

                if (inputdata.length() == 1 && (inputdata.charAt(0) == 'Q' || inputdata.charAt(0) == 'q')) {
                    break;
                }

                String stringArray = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < inputdata.length(); i++) {
                    if (inputdata.charAt(i) > 64 && inputdata.charAt(i) <= 122) { // returns true if both conditions
                                                                                  // returns true
                        // adding characters into empty string
                        stringArray = stringArray + inputdata.charAt(i);
                    }

                }
                System.out.print("Input string without special characters: " + stringArray);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Its working now and I officially learned it. Thanks to you. Peace out!

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop to read the inputs and break the loop if the input is 'Q'.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a word or press 'Q' to quit: ");
            String word = sc.nextLine();
            
            if ("q".equalsIgnoreCase(word))
                break;
            
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Exiting... ");
}
```

Comment: it's better to recommend !"q".equalsIgnoreCase(word). In this case it won't make that much difference, but if you're used to putting the String literal as parameter, sooner or later that 'll cause NPE's

Comment: I agree, it's a valid statement

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line:

```java
while (stringArray != "q" || stringArray != "Q")
```

This repeats while `stringArray` is not `"q"` **or** not `"Q"`. In other words, it must be both `"q"` and `"Q"` at the same time for it to exit, which is not possible.

What you actually wanted is to use `&&`:

```java
while (stringArray != "q" && stringArray != "Q")
```

Repeat while not `"q"` **and also** not `"Q"`.

While this is the root of your problem, I'll still advice you to use the answer that you accepted already.

Edit: As commented, you also shouldn't be comparing strings with `==` or `!=`.

```java
while (!"q".equals(stringArray) && !"Q".equals(stringArray))
```

And you might as well use `equalsIgnoreCase` like in the other answer then. I simply wanted to point out the main flaw in the logic of using `||` instead of `&&` here.

Comment: no, he doesn't want to do that. You should never compare the values of objects with == or !=. What you are doing, is a referential comparison, not a comparison based on value.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments but its still not working but the code is okay

Comment: @Stultuske Added an edit regarding `==` and `!=` for strings. Though, that was not the point I was making in this answer.